Can I poison a class instance in C#
I am trying to add some Dispose cleanup in a large hierarchy where the default dispose method used to do nothing.  When I do so, I get very rare and difficult to reproduce bugs that make me suspect that I have a use after dispose bug somewhere in the large codebase, that went latent for years, because the dispose methods that used to do nothing now do things.  I am not sure even which class causes the bug.
I am wondering if there is any way I can not only dispose of an arbitrary class, but then poison it so that anyone who touches that class in the future is immediately going to make something terrible (and catchable) happen.  I am confident that if I could find the first use after the dispose I could easily work backward to the dispose.  Right now, I just know that something bad happens sometimes, and not even every time I run the test.
I recognize that I am working against the language here because C# tries very hard to keep everything type safe.  I know this is bad C#, but it's just for some test code.  I am not above reflection, or unsafe code, or breaking other rules to make this happen.  I would like to put an arbitrary object into such a bad state that doing anything with it is a fatal error.
Notice I need to poison the object, not the reference to the object.  Poisoning a reference is easy -- just set it to null.
Notice also that if this were a small hierarchy, I could just add an "am I disposed" flag and check it at every method entrance.  Unfortunately, I am at the root of a very large hierarchy, so this is not a reasonable solution to the problem right now.

Technically, what you describe in the last paragraph is the correct implementation of the Dispose pattern. Your methods should throw an exception if the object is disposed.

What actually happens when you experience your bug?

I've had success with something similar using the .NET Framework several years ago (I haven't tried it on anything after .NET 4) - have you looked at AOP (something like PostSharp or KingAOP)? You should just be able to add attributes to classes, and the AOP post-compiler will re-write your IL to include a dispose implementation as you dictate. It's fairly complicated to get right, but once it's done, it's reusable.

These dispose methods that now "do something" - how many of them are there? What do they do? If they dispose of some depended-upon disposable resource (eg a MemoryStream), do you not naturally start to get objectdisposed exceptions? Or are you saying that there may be other methods of your class that do not use the dependency and will merrily carry on working even after dispose? That's a root problem here; poor disposal practice.. Don't forget you can write code that writes code; you can write something that adds that flag for you - it could be a regex find replace, vs extension or even an app

Can you give us some numbers? How large is a "very large hierarchy"? How many suspect classes are we talking about?  I would actually recommend to add a IsDisposed flag and have a first line of ThrowIfDisposed in each public member method (and maybe even property getters).
